# Controller as syntax not passing new obj to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

So I've been trying to use the Controller as syntax in my angular recently but I think I may have a problem understanding how it works. So I'm following a tut which uses `$scope` to bind the members of the controller function as opposed to `this` (i.e. var vm = this). The code is suppose to pass a newly created bookmark to a bookmarks array defined in the controller. The error is in my createBookmark(bookmark) and how I set up angular in index.html. I just can't get my head around why it's not pushing the new bookmark to the bookmarks array. I tried defining it as createBookmark(vm.bookmark) but this is invalid syntax.

I would appreciate any explanations as to why this is wrong.

main.controller.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.categories = [
        { 'id': 0, 'name': 'Development' },
        { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Design' },
        { 'id': 2, 'name': 'Exercise' },
        { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Humor' }
    ];

    vm.bookmarks = [
        { 'id': 0, 'title': 'AngularJS', 'url': 'http://angularjs.org', 'category': 'Development' },
        { 'id': 1, 'title': 'Egghead.io', 'url': 'http://egghead.io', 'category': 'Development' },  
    ];

    vm.currentCategory = null;

    vm.setCurrentCategory = setCurrentCategory;
    vm.isCurrentCategory = isCurrentCategory;

    vm.isCreating = false;
    vm.isEditing = false;

    vm.startCreating = startCreating;
    vm.cancelCreating = cancelCreating;
    vm.startEditing = startEditing;
    vm.cancelEditing = cancelEditing;
    vm.shouldShowCreating = shouldShowCreating;
    vm.shouldShowEditing = shouldShowEditing;

    function setCurrentCategory(category) {
        vm.currentCategory = category;
        vm.cancelCreating();
        vm.cancelEditing();
    }

    function isCurrentCategory(category) {
        return vm.currentCategory !== null && category.name === vm.currentCategory.name;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // CRUD
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function resetCreateForm() {
        vm.newBookmark = {
            title: "",
            url: "",
            category: vm.currentCategory
        };
    }

    function createBookmark(bookmark) {
        bookmark.id = vm.bookmarks.length;
        vm.bookmarks.push(bookmark);

        resetCreateForm();
    }

    vm.createBookmark = createBookmark;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // CREATING AND EDITING STATES
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function startCreating() {
        vm.isCreating = true;
        vm.isEditing = false;

        resetCreateForm();
    }

    function cancelCreating() {
        vm.isCreating = false;
    }

    function shouldShowCreating() {
        return vm.currentCategory && !vm.isEditing;
    }
```

index.html

```
<!-- Content: Bookmarks-->
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <div ng-repeat="bookmark in vm.bookmarks | filter:{category:vm.currentCategory.name}">
                <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="vm.startEditing()" class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            </button>
                <a href="{{ bookmark.url }}" target="_blank">{{ bookmark.title }}</a>
            </div>
            <hr>

            <!-- Creating -->
            <div ng-if="vm.shouldShowCreating()">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="vm.startCreating()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    Create Bookmark
                </button>

               <form class="create-form"  ng-show="vm.isCreating" role="form" ng-submit="vm.createBookmark(vm.newBookmark)" novalidate>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="newBookmarkTitle">Bookmark Title</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBookmarkTitle" ng-model="vm.newBookmark.title" placeholder="Enter title">
                   </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="newBookmarkUrl">Bookmark URL</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBookmarkURL" ng-model="vm.newBookmark.url" placeholder="Enter URL">
                   </div>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Create</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right" ng-click="vm.cancelCreating()">Cancel</button>
               </form>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply passing the *reference* for `vm.newBookmark` into your `vm.createBookmark` function.  You aren't creating a new object at all (regardless of whether or not you use controller as syntax).

You should clone the object before pushing it so that you don't reset the newly pushed object (via `resetCreateForm()`) or try to push the same object reference into your array.

```
function createBookmark(bookmark) {
    var copiedBookmark = angular.copy(bookmark);
    copiedBookmark.id = vm.bookmarks.length;
    vm.bookmarks.push(copiedBookmark);

    resetCreateForm();
}
```